# Enabling back button while SMS OTP Authentication to Update the Mobile number of the User in wso2 identity Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 identity server 5.10 version and I have requirement where in I have to enable a back button to the user while he's in SMS OTP page Since because I have a scenario where in I have enabled two factor authentication (SMS OTP) while logging in to the Application.

1. When the user is trying to login and hasn't registered his mobile number in IDAM, as i have enabled SMS OTP as a two factor Authentication, it will redirect the user to Mobile.jsp page to enter the Mobile Number, so that the user will get a OTP, but
2. When the user enters the mobile number incorrectly, that is directly registered in IDAM, but the user will not get the OTP as he has entered incorrect mobile number, Therefore I have to enable a back button so that the user can update his/her mobile number, So what changes should I perform in the back end Source code and in JSP files in order to make this work. Any help is highly Appreciated.